# Use Castle.Windsor with SSW Data Onion for Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm working on integrating a legacy database with [Asp.Net Zero](http://www.aspnetzero.com).  I created the model classes using [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](http://reversepoco.com) in a separate Models class library project.  I also reversed engineered the DbContext into a separate Data class library project.  I would like to use the [Data Onion](http://sswdataonion.com/user-guide#ef6-configs-other) framework for my repositories and unit of work.  When I use the recommended IOC container [Autofaq](http://autofac.org) my Test Winform application works correctly.

However, the Web Project utilizes [Castle.Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor).  **I'm uncertain on how to do the wire-up.**

I'm creating a new container called *ClientDesktopContainer*:

```
internal class ClientDesktopContainer : WindsorContainer
{
    public ClientDesktopContainer()
    {
        RegisterComponents();
    }

    private void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbContext"].ConnectionString;

        // Data Onion
        Component.For<IDbContextFactory>().ImplementedBy<DbContextFactory>()
            .DependsOn(new DbContextConfig(connectionstring, typeof(MyDbContext), new MigrateToLatestVersion(new Seeder())));
        Component.For<IDbContextScope>().ImplementedBy<DbContextScope>();
        Component.For<IDbContextScopeFactory>().ImplementedBy<DbContextScopeFactory>();
        Component.For<IAmbientDbContextLocator>().ImplementedBy<AmbientDbContextLocator>();
        Component.For<IDbContextReadOnlyScope>().ImplementedBy<DbContextReadOnlyScope>();

        // Data Onion Unit of Work
        Component.For<IRepositoryLocator>().ImplementedBy<RepositoryLocator>();
        // Component.For<IRepositoryResolver>().ImplementedBy<CastleWindsorRepositoryResolver>();
        Component.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWorkFactory>();
        Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>();
        Component.For<IReadOnlyUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<IReadOnlyUnitOfWork>();

        // Custom
        Component.For<IRepository<Enrollment>>()
                 .ImplementedBy<BaseRepository<Enrollment, MyDbContext>>();
}
```

My application invocation code is *Program*:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        IoC.Initialize(new ClientDesktopContainer());

        var dbContextScopeFactor = IoC.Resolve<IDbContextScopeFactory>();
        using (var dbReadOnly = dbContextScopeFactor.CreateReadOnly())
        {
            var context = dbReadOnly.DbContexts.Get<MyDbContext>();

            var individuals = context.Enrollments.ToList();
            foreach (var individual in individuals)
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }

        Application.Run(new ViewMain());
    }
}
```

I created a static *IOC*:

```
public static class IoC
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;

    public static void Initialize(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve<T>();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The Data Onion documentation mentions registering a custom Resolver for IRepositoryResolver.

I created a *CastleWindsorRepositoryResolver*:

```
public class CastleWindsorRepositoryResolver : IRepositoryResolver
{
    public IRepository<TEntity> Resolve<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        // TODO: Resolve wire-up goes here
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm receiving a *ComponentNotFoundExpection*:
[image: Exception]

### Updated to fix constructor parameter for DbContextFactory (to RegisterComponents method):

```
   var dbContextConfig = new DbContextConfig[]
        {
            new DbContextConfig(
                connectionString,
            typeof(MyDbContext),
            new MigrateToLatestVersion(new Seeder())
            ) 
        };

        // Data Onion
        Register(Component.For<IDbContextFactory>().ImplementedBy<DbContextFactory>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<DbContextConfig[]>(dbContextConfig)));
```

Comment: You are using it wrong, to register components in Windsor.Castle wrap calls to `Component.For` into call to `_container.Register`, check this: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/basic-tutorial.md#use-class-library

Comment: @csharpfolk could you elaborate?  I thought I was doing that in my ClientDesktopContainer class which I create through my IoC static.

Comment: Sorry to ask @CyberUnDead this, but how are you creating the repositories using data onion? I want to use Data Onion 2 but I can't find how to integrate it with the Unit of Work way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add call to `Register` in:

```
internal class ClientDesktopContainer : WindsorContainer
{
    public ClientDesktopContainer()
    {
        RegisterComponents();
    }

    private void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbContext"].ConnectionString;

         /* HERE CALL TO REGISTER: */
         this.Register(

        // Data Onion
        Component.For<IDbContextFactory>().ImplementedBy<DbContextFactory>()
            .DependsOn(new DbContextConfig(connectionstring, typeof(MyDbContext), new MigrateToLatestVersion(new Seeder()))),
        Component.For<IDbContextScope>().ImplementedBy<DbContextScope>(),
        Component.For<IDbContextScopeFactory>().ImplementedBy<DbContextScopeFactory>(),
        Component.For<IAmbientDbContextLocator>().ImplementedBy<AmbientDbContextLocator>(),
        Component.For<IDbContextReadOnlyScope>().ImplementedBy<DbContextReadOnlyScope>(),

        // Data Onion Unit of Work
        Component.For<IRepositoryLocator>().ImplementedBy<RepositoryLocator>(),
        // Component.For<IRepositoryResolver>().ImplementedBy<CastleWindsorRepositoryResolver>(),
        Component.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWorkFactory>(),
        Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>(),
        Component.For<IReadOnlyUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<IReadOnlyUnitOfWork>(),

        // Custom
        Component.For<IRepository<Enrollment>>()
                 .ImplementedBy<BaseRepository<Enrollment, MyDbContext>>() );
}
```

Without `Register` you are just creating registration object *without* actually putting types in container. Another thing that may help, by default Castle will register components as *singletons* add `LifestyleTranscient` or `PerWebRequest` to your UnitOfWork registrations.